# Catch form submit event in AngularJS, although form validation failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a payment form where I want to listen to the form submit event for metrics purposes, even though the form validation failed (I want to see *intentions* of paying).

My form header:

```
<form id="payment-form" class="form-with-validation" name="paymentForm" ng-submit="submitPaymentForm()">
```

I do have `required` on some form fields.

But even I keep the Submit button as always enabled, Angular catches the event and `submitPaymentForm()` never triggers:

[image: AngularJS form]

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

add `novalidate` like below. Note that novalidate is used to disable browser's native form validation.

```
<form id="payment-form" novalidate ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I still wire in AngularJS' validation code, after my tracking event has fired?